# Intersection with boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space. If $A \subset X$ is a closed set, and $x \notin A$ with $b_r(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ where $b_r(x)$ denotes the open ball centered at $x$ of radius $r$, is it true that $b_r(x) \cap \delta A \neq \emptyset$? ($\delta A$ denotes the boundary of $A$). This seems intuitively true to me but I'm not quite sure how to show that.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\delta A$ contains the limit points of $A$, one may pick $y_1, y_2, ... \in b_r(x) \cap A$ such that $(y_i)$ converge to some point $y\in \delta A$, which is to say $y\in b_r(x) \cap \delta A$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on the last part? How does $|y_{k+1} - y_k| < 2^{-k}$ implies that $(y_i)$ converges to some point $y \in \delta A$?